# socket programming using TCP and UDP file transfer

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, file-transfer

Im doing socket programming and within the code i open the list of files using TCP socket programming but i have to download a particular file from the server to the client using UDP socket programming but when i download the file it doesn't contain any of whats in the file. please help. the file used is file1.txt which could contain anything but i need for the code to be corrected to provide the information inside the file to display in the client side of the download.  ive been trying foe days to fix it but nothing has been working. this is the code

server.py

```
from socket import *
import os
import sys
import time
SIZE = 1024
serverPort = 1749
serverUDPPort = 9968
fileName = sys.argv[0]
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocketUDP = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('The server is running')
 
while True:
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() #accept connection from client
clientMessage = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode() #client receives file
#print(clientMessage)
s = ""
 
if clientMessage == "listallfiles":
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
s += f + " "
connectionSocket.send(s.encode())
#connectionSocket.send("EOF".encode())
 
elif clientMessage.startswith("download "):
clientMessage = connectionSocket.recvfrom(1024).decode() #client receives file
if clientMessage == "download all": #if the clients whats to download all the files
print("")

 
else: #if the client wants to download just one file use UDP
end = len(clientMessage)
fileName == clientMessage[9:end]
serverSocketUDP.sendto(fileName,("", serverUDPPort))
print ("sending...")
 
fls = open(fileName, "r")
data = fls.read(1024)
#serverSocketUDP.sendto(fileName,addr)
#serverSocketUDP.sendto(data,addr)

 
while(data):
if(serverSocketUDP.sendto(data, ("", serverUDPPort))):
data = fls.read(1024)
time.sleep(0.02)
 
serverSocketUDP.close()
fls.close()
break
 
#if client wants to exit socket
elif clientMessage == "exit":
clientMessage = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode() #client receives file
print(clientMessage)
connectionSocket.close()
```

client.py

```
from select import select
from socket import *
import sys
import time
serverName = '127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 1749
serverUDPPort = 9968
fileName = sys.argv[0]
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocketUDP = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
clientSocketUDP.bind((serverName,serverUDPPort))
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort)) #connecting to server TCP
clientSocketUDP.connect((serverName, serverPort)) #connecting to server UDP
while True:
sentence = input("")
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode()) #sends message to server
 
s = ""
#while (True):
if sentence == "listallfiles":
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024) #it is receiving message form server
#if modifiedSentence == "EOF".encode():
# break
s += modifiedSentence.decode()
print(s)

elif sentence.startswith("download "):
#clientSocketUDP.sendto(sentence.encode(), (serverName, serverUDPPort)) #sends message to server
#downloading all files
if sentence == "download all":
while (1):
print("")
 
#download one file
else:
end = len(sentence)
fileName == sentence[9:end]
while True:
data,addr = clientSocketUDP.recvfrom(1024) #download one using UDP
if data:
print ("file name: ", data)
 
fls = open(sentence, 'wb')
while True:
ready = select.select([clientSocketUDP], [], [], timeout)
if ready[0]:
data, addr = clientSocketUDP.recvfrom(1024)
fls.write(data)
else:
fls.close()
break

#try:
# while (data):
# fls.write(data)
# clientSocketUDP.settimeout(2)
# data,addr = clientSocketUDP.recvfrom(1024) #download one using UDP
#except timeout:
# fls.close()
# clientSocketUDP.close()
# #time.sleep(0.02)
 
#if client wants to exit socket
elif sentence == "exit":
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode()) #send exit message to server
clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: Please fix the code's indentation, the whitespace matters in Python

Comment: it doesn't transfer the data in the file over. it downloads an empty file.

Comment: the indentation is done on my laptop but when it transfers the data it doesn't shows whats inside the file on the client side just shows its downloaded but empty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)